# typescript error: ' ' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, graphql-codegen

I went through several similar questions but wasn't able to get anywhere in solving this. I was following along with a tutorial from 2019 and I'm having trouble figuring out the right way to do the same thing in 2020. Here's the line I'm getting an error on:

`ERROR: 'HotelsQuery' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.ts(2702)`

`type IHotelsProps = HotelsQuery.Props<IHotelsBaseProps> & RouteComponentProps;`

I'm passing HotelsQuery from my generatedModels file, defined as:

```
export type HotelsQuery = (
  { __typename?: 'Query' }
  & { hotels?: Maybe<(
    { __typename?: 'HotelTypeConnection' }
    & { edges: Array<Maybe<(
      { __typename?: 'HotelTypeEdge' }
      & { node?: Maybe<(
        { __typename?: 'HotelType' }
        & Pick<HotelType, 'id' | 'title' | 'body'>
      )> }
    )>> }
  )> }
);
```

And the class it's being passed to:

```
class Hotels extends React.Component<IHotelsProps, IHotelsState> {
    constructor(props: IHotelsProps) {
        super(props);
        const query = queryString.parse(props.location.search);
        this.state = {
            searchQuery: query && query.search
            ? query.search.toString() : undefined
        };
    }

    public render() {
        const { searchQuery } = this.state;
        const { data } = this.props;

        return (
            <Row>
                <Col span={12} offset={6}>
                    <Divider>Add Hotel</Divider>
                    <Divider>Hotels</Divider>
                    <Input.Search
                        placeholder="Search..."
                        enterButton="Search"
                        defaultValue={searchQuery}
                        onChange={this.handleSearchQueryChange}
                        onSearch={this.handleSearch}
                    />
                    {data!.loading ? (
                        <Spin style={{ marginTop: 16, display: 'block' }} /> )
                        : (
                            <div>
                                {data!.notes!.edges.map(edge => (
                                <Card
                                    key={edge!.node!.id}
                                    style={{ marginTop: 16 }}
                                    actions={[
                                        <Icon
                                            type="delete"
                                            key={edge!.node!.id}
                                            onClick={() => this.handleDeleteHotel(edge!.node!.id)}
                                        />
                                    ]}
                                >
                                    <Card.Meta
                                        title={edge!.node!.title}
                                        description={edge!.node!.body}
                                    />
                                </Card>
                            ))}
                            </div>
                        )}
                </Col>
            </Row>
        );
    }
```

Comment: what are you expecting `HotelsQuery.Props` to resolve to?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I just added the class that it's being passed to to the code in the initial question, if that helps?

Comment: not really, you say `HotelsQuery` is from `generatedModels` file, does that mean it was auto-generated? What decided the type looks like that because it certainly doesn't look like it would support anything along the lines of how you are trying to use it.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I used yarn generate to generate the models from my yml file.  Since I'm following a tutorial that isn't super recent, I have to assume the way the dependencies are interacting is different than it used to be

Comment: could you link to the tutorial you are using? It seems highly dependent on specifics in that, I'd rather look at it myself than ask you to hunt down what `yarn generate` is actually doing.

Comment: sure, here's the tutorial (it's a notes app but I'm substituting hotels in mine) 
https://apirobot.me/posts/django-react-ts-how-to-create-and-consume-graphql-api

Comment: `HotelsQuery ` is a namespace in the tutorial code, not a type so that explains the syntax   for getting `Props` which is correct and the error since you are defining it as a type. The source of your problem is that `HotelsQuery` is incorrectly defined. It should be a namespace with a Props property which is a generic type definition. I'm also not saying the definition you have for `HotelsQuery` above should be the definition for `Props` in the namespace. I haven't gone through the tutorial. If @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen is going through the tutorial they'll be able to provide more details.

Answer (score -1):

So I took a stab at [the tutorial](https://apirobot.me/posts/django-react-ts-how-to-create-and-consume-graphql-api#graphql-code-generator) and wanted to explain how a few parts are working.

First off I only did the front end part so when it came time to running `yarn  gql-gen` I hit a block since the `codegen.yml` references the backend server for getting the types (I assume?)

```yaml
overwrite: true
schema: "<http://localhost:8000/graphql/>"
documents: "src/**/*.ts"
generates:
    ./src/generatedModels.tsx:
        config: {}
        plugins:
            - "typescript-common"
            - "typescript-client"
            - "typescript-react-apollo"
```

Here `schema` is referring to localhost, so I think you need to have the backend configured correctly to expose the types at `/graphql/` directory. I just got an error saying I had no sources so either that didn't happen for you because you had the backend setup **or you found another work around that might have been incorrect.**

```
user@computer simplenote % yarn gql-gen --config codegen.yml
yarn run v1.22.5
$ /.../simplenote/node_modules/.bin/gql-gen --config codegen.yml
/.../simplenote/node_modules/graphql/jsutils/devAssert.js:12
    throw new Error(message);
    ^

Error: Must provide Source. Received: undefined.
```

I do want to point out that the path `node_modules/.bin/gql-gen` indicates what it is actually using, that is a link to `node_modules/graphql-code-generator/__/cli.js` so the library you are actually using with the `yarn gpl-gen` is [graphql code generator](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-react-apollo) so the documentation on their site may be of help.

So some options for a way forward I would recommend:

1. look at the config options in the [graphql TypeScript React Apollo](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-react-apollo) docs, there may be default options that have changed since the tutorial was written, in particular hooks are replacing HOCs a lot so it's possible the defaults being different is because of that.
2. re-check that the backend part is running when you run `yarn gql-gen` and that if you go to `http://localhost:8000/graphql/` in your browser I'd expect some kind of data dump, otherwise the `codegen.yml` may be unable to get the info it needs to generate relevant type definitions.
3. abandon using HOCs and move to [using hooks](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-react-apollo#usage-example), the rest of the tutorial will still probably work you just have a function component instead of a class and use probably `useHotels` from the code generated.  I do highly recommend using hooks, there is a good reason they so rapidly replaced HOCs.

I hope one or both of these leads you in enough of a right direction to figure out how to proceed, happy hunting :)